# What are swo and swp files in JBoss log dir?

Tags: java, logging, file, jboss

I have files

```
server.log
.server.log.swo
.server.log.swp
```

how to open swo and swp?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Those are temporary files created by the vim editor. The .swp is created when a file is opened in the editor. The .swo is created if the file is edited and the .swp already exists. Edit it a third time and you get a .swn, and so on. When vim is closed, those files should go away. If vim crashes or is killed, they may be left behind. They are safe to ignore.

Comment: How can we get rid of them safely?

Answer (score 3):

the files remain even after vim is closed we need to use vim in recover mode, save and then move the files to a different name. then delete the .sw* files.